# Perl does not match multiple lines

Tags: shell, perl

I want to match:

```
Start Here Some example
text covering a few
lines. End Here
```

So I do

```
$ perl -nle 'print $1 if /(Start Here.*?)End Here/s'
```

then paste the text above and `ctr-D`.  It wont match from cmd - but it does in file script. Why?

Comment: You are reading the file line by line, then it is not possible to match multiple lines since `$_` will only contain a single line at a time. Instead read the file into one string, or read it by paragraph

Comment: So I can simply `undef` at the beginning the `$/`, and will regex through all words delimited by whitespace?

Comment: What do you mean by *"will regex through all words..."* ?

Comment: You can also run your script like this `perl -0777 -nle ....`

Comment: I meant, in case the the `$/` is undef, the the `$_` is no longer one line? Or how can I slurp the file in the `$_`, so I can then match the regex I have tried?

Comment: Did you try the `-0777` switch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have explained, you're reading your file a line at a time, so matches over multiple lines are never going to work.

Reading files a line at a time is often the best approach. So we can use the "flip-flip" operator to do this:

```
 $ perl -nle 'print if /Start Here/ .. /End Here/' your_file_here
```

Comment: But how is possible to use /Start Here/, but use one line after it (I do not want to use /Start there/ at the the line, because the earlier has better match), How can I use `$.` line numbering or anything other to achive this?

Comment: Or if I want to edit just one line from the range specified by the flip-flop regex lines? Because, If it is used in `while` loop, the the effect of the editting will be to all lines within the range. How to specifie just particular line from the range?

Comment: Sory, I did it, just added another regex in condition matching specified line

Answer (score 3):

Change input record separator (`$/`) to null using `-0` command line switch.

```
perl -0777nle 'print $1 if /(Start Here.*?)End Here/s' <<END
Start Here Some example
text covering a few
lines. End Here
THE_END
```

[man perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)

> -0[octal/hexadecimal]
>               specifies the input record separator ($/) as an octal or
>               hexadecimal number. […] Any value 0400 or above will cause Perl to slurp files whole, but by convention the value 0777 is the one normally used for this purpose.

[man perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

> IO::Handle->input_record_separator( EXPR )
>   $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR
>   $RS
>   $/
>   The input record separator, newline by default.  This influences Perl's idea of what a "line" is. […]  You may set it to […] "undef" to read through the end of file.